# need to use 1 sql to do these 3 steps

Tags: sql

I have to report on specific records. Our orders have many lines of detail, sometimes hundreds. We record everything which happens to an order. We are looking for a report that shows which orders originally were quotes - there would be an transaction code of QEE or QNE or QEP for that order. then if the order also has a @23 this tells us it 'converted' to an order.

1. Here we select all order# which have one of the 'Q' as a transaction code (ottrnc).

   ```
   create view mylib.quote1 as SELECT t1.otord#                    
            FROM astdta.OETRANOT t1                        
            WHERE t1.ottrnc IN ('QEE','QNE', 'QEP')
   ```
2. Here we use the view QUOTE1, it would create a second view QUOTE2.

   ```
   SELECT                                               
     ALL       T01.OTORD#                               
     FROM      mylib/QUOTE1 T01 LEFT OUTER JOIN         
               ASTCCDTA/OETRA99 T02                     
     ON        T01.OTORD# = T02.OTORD#                  
     WHERE     T02.OTTRNC = '@23'
   ```
3. then in report tool we are joining   QUOTE2 to ASTCCDTA/OETRA99 so that we are showing all data for those order# which have 1 of the Q's and also the @23.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the order column is called on ASTCCDTA/OETRA99 but you want something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.otord#
FROM astdta.OETRANOT T01
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
ASTCCDTA/OETRA99 T02
ON T01.OTORD# = T02.OTORD#
JOIN ASTCCDTA/OETRA99 T03
ON T03.otord3 = T01.otord#
WHERE T02.OTTRNC = '@23'
AND T01.ottrnc IN ('QEE','QNE', 'QEP')
```

OR

```
SELECT t1.otord#
FROM astdta.OETRANOT T01
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
ASTCCDTA/OETRA99 T02
ON T01.OTORD# = T02.OTORD#
JOIN ASTCCDTA/OETRA99 T03
ON T03.otord3 = T01.otord#
WHERE T02.OTTRNC = '@23'
AND T01.ottrnc IN ('QEE','QNE', 'QEP')
GROUP BY t1.otord#
```

Comment: this is good. one thing i see it makes duplicates because there can be more than 1 'q' type per order# or even more than  1 @23 type. can this be made as distinct across the board?